# Autocorrelation digital logic design

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, verilog, dsp, digital-filter

I'm trying to implement a autocorrelation module into my FPGA. I have been doing some research on the internet and there are some complicated and advanced methods that use a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) to do the autocorrelation.

However, all I need is a simple implementation, nothing too fancy. I came across this [digital logic site](https://www.physics.umd.edu/hep/drew/programmable/autocorrelation.html#correlation) that has this diagram:

[image: Design from autocorrelation website]

Essentially, what I got out of this was that we chain D-flip-flops (DFF) to create a shift register. From there we pull from the shift register or different DFFs and run them into a multiplier with the original S<sub>i</sub>, then add the output. So my implementation from a program called [digital](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital) is this:

[image: Implementation using Digital application]

Which I believe is the same, however, I am noticing some variations. I added more DFFs because I want to be able to correlate more bits. I also am not really sure if I implemented the "Sums" correctly; I also skipped the fist add from the first multiply for this reason.

Some other issues I had include issues from the program. I ultimately used this program because I can take the design and get Verilog code out of it. But when I try to export as Verilog I get the error:

[image: Verilog import error]

Can anyone help confirm if I'm on the right track with this implementation or if it is correct? It seems like the first adder is having issues but I am also unsure of what the first C<sub>i</sub> would be. In Verilog I could just set it to a 0 bit, but I am not sure how to do that in a design.

Answer (score 1):

The block diagram implementation is incorrect.

Firstly, let me quickly clarify what [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) is, with reference to the example you have shared. It should help you to draw the diagram correctly. (Note: The standard time indexing notation for eg. in Wikipedia is different from what is used [here](https://www.physics.umd.edu/hep/drew/programmable/autocorrelation.html#correlation))

I'll assume that I have \$N\$ readings sent into the system in the order \$S_N, S_{N-1}, \dots S_1, S_0\$. The autocorrelation of this discrete-time signal \$S_n\$ at a time lag \$k\$ is

$$R_{ss}(k)=\sum_{k=0}^{N}S_i\cdot S_{i+k}$$

For a 5-stage autocorrelation as given in your example, there are 5 outputs.

The autocorrelation at lag \$k=0,1,\dots 4\$ is
$$ R_{ss}(0) = A_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{N}S_i\cdot S_{i}$$
$$ R_{ss}(1) = A_2 = \sum_{k=0}^{N}S_i\cdot S_{i+1}$$
$$\dots$$
$$ R_{ss}(4) = A_5 = \sum_{k=0}^{N}S_i\cdot S_{i+4}$$

The product terms at each stage are *accumulated* separately (and not summed up across each stage) to generate the correlation at that particular stage.

I created this up in digital and the connections are shown below.

[image: digital_implementation]

To create an accumulator I used a D register to which I keep adding the product terms each cycle. I fed in the samples \$1,2,3,4\$ and obtained the expected correlation values \$30,20,11,4\$.

I used an 8-bit D register to store the input samples. Since the multiplication of two 8-bit numbers results in a 16-bit number, I used 16-bit adders and registers subsequent to the multiplication stage. The bit width of the output registers must be carefully designed to accommodate the maximum possible value.